# What's the difference between AC and DC and why do we need them both?

Tags: ac, dc

I read so many articles on the subject and still can't get the difference between AC and DC. I know that, for example, light bulbs in my house glow using AC. Why don't they use DC? Why does our house use AC instead of DC? Why do we have to convert AC to DC? Light bulb can glow using both AC (power outlets) and DC (battery). What's the difference between AC and DC and why do we need them both?

Comment: You could look up "war of the currents" as a good starting point.

Comment: *I read so many articles on the subject and still can't get the difference between AC and DC.* - I find it hard to believe that one won't see the difference after reading even one article on the subject assuming that one is of acceptable quality.

Comment: Early 1900's it was a discussion between Edison and Tesla. A lot of  info on web.

Comment: it is cheaper to stepup voltage to transport in AC then step down to distribute and AC motors without brushes last longer.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason AC won out over DC is the ability to transmit power over transmission lines for long distances.  It is easy to use transformers to change the voltage of AC, using high voltage for efficient transmission over distance then and transforming to lower voltages for residential use.  You could use DC from solar cells and batteries when the power generated is used only in a single  residence or building.  Until the advent of modern electronics, it wasn't practical to send DC over long distances because changing DC to different voltages efficiently isn't trivial.

Note: the power loss over a power line is the current squared times the resistance of the power line, P = I^2 * R.  The transmitted power is the current times the voltage P = V * I.  Thus, higher voltages can transmit the same power with a lower current.

Comment: "it isn't practical to send DC over long distances" - on the contrary, there are High Voltage DC power lines all over the world and they have some advantages. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current)

Comment: But efficiently lowering the DC voltage without significant power loss isn't trivial.   AC transformers have been around as long as AC power.

Comment: @Finbar Do you know of anyone in actual practice converting HVDC transmission to LVDC for customer use.  The conversions appear to be AC to DC and DC to AC when converting the power to the desired voltage.  I'm not meaning DC to AC to DC as DC to DC.

Comment: Note, a switching power supply would essentially do DC to AC to DC, although it usually uses a higher frequency that 60 Hz.  However, in practicality you might look at it as DC to DC.  But, I haven't seen a switching power supply with an input volatage of 100 kV.

Comment: @@Finbar  See how I edited the answer.

Comment: Indeed, shame the question has already been closed :(

Comment: With more focus to the question it could be reopened.